# Did I use recursion correctly?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm working through some practice JavaScript problems, and solved a problem involving recursion. Although I got it right, my implementation is different from the "official" solution, so I was wondering if anyone had any insight on whether the official answer is better and if so, why.

**Question**

> Implement a function that takes a function as its first argument, a number `num` as its second argument, then executes the passed in function `num` times.
>   It's ok to use a loop in your implementation, bonus points if you use recursion instead.

**My Solution**

```
function repeat(operation, num) {
    if (num > 0) {
        operation();

        repeat(operation, num - 1);
    };
};
```

**Given Solution**

```
function repeat(operation, num) {
    if (num <= 0)
        return;

    operation();

    return repeat(operation, --num);
};
```

Is there anything about the given solution that makes it better than mine?

Comment: The opposite logic on the if statement is irrelevant, but I think the lack of a `return` in front of the `repeat(...)` is a problem.

Comment: @MackieeE Why is this important? In my eyes this seem fine. Recursion means a function calling itself.

Comment: @LilDevil - since there is no return value and no code after the `repeat()` statement, no return is needed.

Comment: Shouldn't this be better asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @LilDevil the function returns undefined, then you don't need a return. Also if you don't write return there, the function will stop recursion correctly anyway because if the "opposite logic" if you're talking about

Comment: @Zorgatone This *might*, by some, be considered example code (which is off-topic on CR), it seems to also be a bit about explaining code rather than improving it. It does not necessarily belong on Code Review. I find this to be a quite good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @SimonForsberg good point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a specific reason to directly return the result of a recursive call. This is called "tail recursion", and a clever run-time environment can optimise for that case and execute without using any additional stack space for the recursive calls (it simply reuses the stack space of the current function). In the latest ECMAScipt 6 specification (Javascript to you and me) it specifically calls out that the runtime environment should optimise tail-recursive calls.

In practice, your code does in fact not do anything after the recursive call, so it is properly tail-recursive. Putting the recursive call with a return statement makes it clear that it should be a tail-recursive call, and a bit more likely that the run-time environment will correctly optimise it.

Comment: It's not his code with proper tail-recursion, but the given solution. Just the other way around :P

Comment: both are properly tail recursive in that no code is executed before the function exits. A proper optimiser should be able to recognise that in Juan's code, but I wouldn't necessarily count on it.

Comment: It's really interesting to know that ES6 favors tail recursion. Thank you, and everyone else who contributed this useful information.

Answer (score 5):

Just bear in the mind. There is something that every JavaScript developer MUST know. If recursion continues very long time the browser can kill your script or alert error to user. Often JavaScript developers uses approaches like this:

```
var inputArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

(function handleArray() {
    var currentElement = inputArray.shift();
    // do something with currentElement 
    if (inputArray.length > 0 ) {
        setTimeout(handleArray, 0);
    }
}());
```

In this way you will break long time operation on small parts.

Comment: Can you provide use futher reference of external resources, about this practice to call the next recursion with a timeout?

I understand your argument, and I find it valid. I just wanted to point out it could be an interesting reading for anyone coming here

Answer (score 4):

The solutions are identical, but in practice the given solution is easier to understand. There is a clear "base case," and the recursion is done in the `return` statement. Both of these properties lead to better code quality and readability when dealing with recursive functions.